# How to stop arrow keys from expanding/collapsing property grid members

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

I have a property grid in C++/CLI (it's a .net control so the language doesn't matter much).
My issue is that even i have my mouse over another panel the arrow keys still expand or collapse the members of the property grid.
Is there a way to stop this?
I believe that clicking on a different panel doesn't un-focus the property grid, but i would not mind also permanently disabling the arrow keys for this property grid.

Edit:
Some more detail:
The property grid and the panel in question are part of a Splitter Panel

Edit2
Well i tried catching the key in a KeyPressed() event handler and set it to handled, but somehow this doesn't get called. The Form KeyPress gets called, but even setting the event as handled there if the key is what i am interested in doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding the IsInputKey method and seeing if that will help you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.isinputkey.aspx

Comment: I tried that and it did not work unfortunately. is there a good place where i can read about the message flow in .net?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook this looks good as well